# How to apply a rotation around the origin with affine transform

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to rotate a rect 45 degrees with affine transform. I know I have to move the context such that the rect is at the origin, apply the rotation and then move back. I want to fully understand how this works so I started with a small test to rotate it around the origin (0,0 in the coordinate system of the parent view), not moving back. This is the view (green rect in this case) after being translated to the origin:

[image]

Then I rotate 10 degrees and it looks like this:

[image]

I expect it to use the origin as pivot, but this looks like the origin was also translated, so when I apply the rotation it looks the same as if I would have applied it in the old position, only translated to other point. What am I missing?

This is the code...

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    UIColor * redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    float x = 150;
    float y = 150;
    float w = 120;
    float h = 40;

    CGRect r = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);


    NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));

    //move to the origin
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-x, -y);
    float rad = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(10); //with 45 it's outside of the view

    CGFloat rotation = rad;

    //rotate
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, rotation);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    r = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The transformations are applied in inverse order, so it will rotate first, and then do the translation.

If I change it like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    UIColor * redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    float x = 150;
    float y = 150;
    float w = 120;
    float h = 40;

    CGRect r = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);


    NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    float rad = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(10);

    CGFloat rotation = rad;

    //rotate
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, rotation);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -x, -y);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    r = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Then it works:

[image]